# Java - string split replace and join

Tags: java

I have a URL string where I need to replace the last collection of characters after the final "/"

In Ruby, this would be:

```
str = "/some/url/structure"
ar = str.split("/")
ar[ar.length-1] = "path"
string = ar.join("/")
>> "/some/url/path"
```

How can I do this in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This snippet demonstrates how to do it with Java:

```
System.out.println("one/two/four".replaceAll("/[^/]+$", "/three"));
```

It takes the input String (`"one/two/four"`) and replaces everything starting from the last slash (including the slash) with the replacement String.

Minor change - `+` instead of `*` leaves urls with a slash as a last char unchanged. Seems a more practical solution to me.

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting this as it is the most concise, and marking the rest as useful as they all arrive at the correct answer

Comment: What is i have "one/three/two/four/two/three" as input string and i want to replace the last "/three" with "mystring" ?...replaceAll() will not replace all occurences of old string to the new string ?

Comment: @Kartrik - it the snippet fulfills the requirement. Try it yourself: http://ideone.com/sXvpY (Great - received the first downvote for a working solution ;-) )

Comment: sorry sorry, by mistake i downvoted your answer. I was actually downvoting last 2nd answer.

Comment: thanks its working yaar..what i thought was it would replace all occurences of old string with new string.. You are Great..

Answer (score 5):

I don't fully understand, what exactly do you want, but you may construct a `StringBuilder` from your string, use it's `lastIndexOf("/")` method to determine last `/` position, and, finally, use `append()` or `replace()` to add something to the end (or instead of the current ending).

Answer (score 2):

Or use this if you are not so used to regular expressions.

```
url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/")+1).concat("newvalue");
```

Answer (score 2):

Frozen Spider is absolutely right. 
You can use the following Code :

```
String str = "/some/url/structure";
int lst=str.lastIndexOf("/");
str=str.replace(str.substring(lst+1),"path");
System.out.println(str);
```

What i did is, i took last index of '\', and replaced the string starting from last '/', with "path".

In Fully Shortest Form:

```
System.out.println(str.replace(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/")+1),"path"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
String str = "/some/url/structure";
    String[] ar = str.split("/");
    int n = ar.length;
    str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {
        str += ar[i] + "/";
    }
    str += "path";
    System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to replace /structure with your content. Then you should try **str.replce('/structure','/parth')**.

Comment: That would also replace `/structure` inside the string `"/foo/structure/bar"` (ie. **not** the last occurrence)